# How are mobile telephony networks like LTE and HSPA encrypted?

Tags: encryption, network, mobile, protocols

How are mobile telephony networks like [LTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3GPP_Long_Term_Evolution) (4G) and [HSPA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/High_Speed_Packet_Access) (3G) encrypted? between what parts is the communication encrypted? who has access to the keys? is symmetric or asymmetric encryption used? is it similar to [TLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security)?

Comment: Independent of the actual implementation of both networks, it is important to consider two major things:
(1) Confidentiality in such mobile communications is not designed to provide end-to-end encryption. An interface for authorities is especially intended.
(2) There is probably an insecure unencrypted mode. Imagine if there is an error in the crypto provider, mobile operators can not deny their service to end users "just" because of that, economically speaking.

Comment: @ordag "_Imagine if there is an error in the crypto provider, mobile operators can not deny their service to end users "just" because of that, economically speaking._" source?

Comment: Depends on a gazillion factors like vendors, implementations, if we're talking about RAN or Core etc. Please specify what exactly you want to know.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that @Jay Looney is correct; for authoritative answers, contact the service provider.  (who will report you to DHS and DMCA).

[Blackhat description of attacks on HSPA](https://media.blackhat.com/bh-dc-11/Perez-Pico/BlackHat_DC_2011_Perez-Pico_Mobile_Attacks-wp.pdf) includes a brief overview and architecture, that may address the portion of the question re: what parts are encrypted.  This resource also includes the following sentence,

> The reality is that most UMTS/HSPA devices are also GSM/GPRS/EDGE capable, and are 
>   configured to try and connect to a GSM/GPRS/EDGE network whenever a suitable UMTS/HSPA network is not available.

I found one source that asserts that the answer is [Feistel encryption](http://www.iup.edu/WorkArea/DownloadAsset.aspx?id=81129), but it doesn't address the key management issue. I continue to believe that is something that only the vendor can answer, and I'm willing to bet they won't.

[Agilent](http://www.home.agilent.com/upload/cmc_upload/All/Security_in_the_LTE-SAE_Network.PDF?&cc=US&lc=eng) provides some internal details, but I think that is more specific than you want. It may be useful as context/example.

You could always [take a course in the subject](http://www.tonex.com/Courses/113/578/) for a mere $1500.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the 4G and 3G networks are not used to make phonecalls or send/recieve texts, those are still pushed to the CDMA and GSM networks and 3/4G are used to connect your device to the internet. The encryption will depend on the company deploying it as well as the device user, because you can setup secure connections to an encrypted VPN or even route through a home proxy. I know my android phone has these features and has retained them through multiple updates. I can only suggest that you call your service provider and ask them how it works.

Comment: Just the fact that battery call time life is quoted as dramatically less on 3/4G than on GSM makes me very skeptical of this.

Comment: I did say "usually" and not all the time, but when I answered this question originally, my answer was accurate, however I am not sure if it remains accurate.